# possible ways to happen memory leaks while using jsp and servlets in development mode

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, memory-leaks

can any one please explain possible ways to happen memory leaks while using jsp and servlets   in development mode?

getting pergemn space exception after started using  `jsp&servlets` .

`eclipse.ini` memory spec i given  :

```
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxNewSize=448m 
-XX:NewSize=448m
```

Comment: This is not about `eclipse` (removed)

Comment: You have to be a little more concrete. What have you done with JSPs and servlets? Typically this is not a JSP or servlet problem, but a problem of your code. Look for some (endless) loops allocating objects or try using VisualVM (or Netbeans) to profile your application.

Comment: If you are running your application through Eclipse, how much memory did you allocate for Eclipse?

Comment: @Adrian its an light weight application ..just dispatching and redirection some jsp's when user clicks on links ...after multiple transactions ..i mean several dispatches and re directions ..pergemn error coming..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are few comments/suggestions on this.

1. You are getting permgen space exception. To understand this error, you need a bit of understanding of **Java memory model** and how the pergen space is used. [Check out this link](http://plumbr.eu/blog/what-is-a-permgen-leak) for a brief overview on this.
2. Basically is region in the heap-space where the object allocated are never reclaimed by garbage collector. There are specific object types are allocated on this region (e.g. Classloaders, Literal pool etc.)
3. Pergen space to be used by JVM can be specified at start up. If you don't specify, it will take some default value.
4. It would be a good idea to **memory-profile** your application. Memory profiling gives a good insight into the actual heap usage. You can check the type and the number of objects being created and then trace them to your code which is doing this.
5. There are lot of commercial and o[pensource profiling tools](http://java-source.net/open-source/profilers) available. You can try some of them. There is [VisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/profiler.html) which comes bundled with JDK.
6. Lastly, setting up appropriate memory settings for JVM is always tuning exercise. Its not about one size fitting all :) and profiling is very vital is tuning your application.

Answer (score 1):

this may be that you are creating connection and on redeploy your project you are not free your connection resources this may be your one of issue of permgem exception.

Comment: really i am not aware of what is connection ..can u please give me a clue ..which type of connection ?

Comment: "Redeploy" could really be an Eclipse problem. While development and automatic redeploy in Eclipse the perm space will run full after some time. Maybe try a simple "load test" without Eclipse.